# HTML - Pull text from another site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just getting into HTML/JavaScript and have a question for you folks.

I'm trying to have my home page pull the title of said site from my web server. if I go to `127.0.0.1/?q=name` it will return lets say "Foo" only. Nothing else just "Foo" in clear text on the page.

I would like my site to dynamically pull this as it loads. Here's the script I tried with an iFrame but it seems to move everything around. Am I overthinking this ?

```
<h1>Welcome to 
    <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/?q=name" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</h1>

Thank you for visiting !
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: Is your home page on the same domain? That is, the HTML in your question is on `127.0.0.1` too?

Comment: Hey, it is. This is just for testing purposes. A similar example is checkip.amazonaws.com -- Notice how it just returns your WAN IP in text? Same concept

Comment: So if you GET `http://127.0.0.1:8080/?q=name`, it returns `Foo`?

Comment: Jack Bashford that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get plain text information from the same domain, an iframe sounds like overkill - you might consider using an ordinary network request instead, and populating a standard element (like a `<span>` when the response comes back:

```
<h1>
  Welcome to <span id="name-span"></span>
</h1>
```

with JS:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/?q=name')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((textResponse) => {
    document.querySelector('#name-span').textContent = textResponse;
  });
```

To populate multiple items in this manner, you might consider using an array instead, for example:

```
const qs = ['name', 'age'];
qs.forEach((q) => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/?q=' + q)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((textResponse) => {
    document.querySelector('#' + q + '-span').textContent = textResponse;
  });
});
```

Note that `fetch` can work if the information you're trying to grab is on the same domain - otherwise, you'll have to use a somewhat-unwieldy `iframe` like you're doing, or bounce the request off of a server instead, else you'll run into CORS issues.

Comment: Is there any way to make this var based? I've got like 10 things on my site that I'd like to do this exact function. What would you say is the best way ?

Answer (score -2):

**TL;DR**

You can't just access an external resource from `Javascript`, this limitation is done for security reasons.

**Possible solutions**

You have already used `iframe`, so I assume you are aware of `the CORS policy`.

You can try to use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), however in that case you need to implement this concept on the server side as well, for be able to provide `callback` argument.

In case the request is made to the same domain, you can just use any time of `XMLHttpRequest`

This could be done with the help of `JQuery` for example.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/?q=name",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#your_h1_or_any_other_selector").append(html);
  }
});
```